# Remove all hex characters from string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding, string-parsing

Although there are similar questions, I can't seem to find a working solution for my case:

I'm encountering some annoying hex chars in strings, e.g.

```
'\xe2\x80\x9chttp://www.google.com\xe2\x80\x9d blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

What I need is to remove these hex `\xHH` characters, and them alone, in order to get the following result:

```
'http://www.google.com blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

decoding doesn't help:

```
s.decode('utf8') # u'\u201chttp://www.google.com\u201d blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just remove all non-ASCII characters:

```
>>> s.decode('utf8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
'http://www.google.com blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

Other possible solution:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = '\xe2\x80\x9chttp://www.google.com\xe2\x80\x9d blah blah#%#@$^blah'
>>> printable = set(string.printable)
>>> filter(lambda x: x in printable, s)
'http://www.google.com blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

Or use Regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', s) 
'http://www.google.com blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

Pick your favorite one.

Comment: I pick the first one :)

Answer (score 9):

These are not "hex characters" but the internal representation (utf-8 encoded in the first case, unicode code point in the second case) of the unicode characters 'LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' ('“') and 'RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' ('”').

```
>>> s = "\xe2\x80\x9chttp://www.google.com\xe2\x80\x9d blah blah#%#@$^blah"
>>> print s
“http://www.google.com” blah blah#%#@$^blah
>>> s.decode("utf-8")
u'\u201chttp://www.google.com\u201d blah blah#%#@$^blah'
>>> print s.decode("utf-8")
“http://www.google.com” blah blah#%#@$^blah
```

As how to remove them, they are just ordinary characters so a simple `str.replace()` will do:

```
>>> s.replace("\xe2\x80\x9c", "").replace("\xe2\x80\x9d", "")
'http://www.google.com blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

If you want to get rid of all non-ascii characters at once, you just have to decode to unicode then encode to ascii with the "ignore" parameter:

```
>>> s.decode("utf-8").encode("ascii", "ignore")
'http://www.google.com blah blah#%#@$^blah'
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @pyd: the question is tagged as python 2.7 and `str` DO have a `decode` method in python 2.7 - which disappeared in python 3 (obviously since py3 strings are unicode so the  `decode` method would make no sense - but it still exists on py3 byte string (type `byte`).

Answer (score 4):

You could make it check for valid letters, and instead of typing out everything, it's possible to use the `string` module. The ones that may be useful to you are `string.ascii_letters` (contains both `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase`), `string.digits`, `string.printable` and `string.punctuation`.

I'd try `string.printable` first, but if it lets a few too many characters through, you could use a mix of the others.

Here's an example of how I'd do it:

```
import string
valid_characters = string.printable
start_string = '\xe2\x80\x9chttp://www.google.com\xe2\x80\x9d blah blah#%#@$^blah'
end_string = ''.join(i for i in start_string if i in valid_characters)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use decode after encoding just like this

```
s.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode("utf-8")
```