# How to remove hex characters in Python

Tags: python

I am trying the following

```py
>>> import string
>>> s = 'https://google.com\n<0x03><0x03><0x03>'
>>> s.decode('utf8').encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

The expected output is:

```py
'https://google.com'
```

But the hex characters and new line is not removed.

Comment: does this answer your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598136/remove-all-hex-characters-from-string-in-python?

Comment: There are no non-ascii characters in your original input `'https://google.com\n<0x03><0x03><0x03>'`

Edit: to clarify `\n` is valid ascii, `<0x03>` are just a series of six ascii characters and aren't raw bytes, also `\x03` is valid ascii

Comment: why do you expect it will remove `\n` or other chars ? ASCII chars are probably from code 0 to 128 - so `03` is ASCII code. If you don't want text after '\n` then use `s = s.split('\n')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
import string
import re
s = 'https://google.com\n<0x03><0x03><0x03>'
s=re.sub(r'[^ -~].*'.format(string.punctuation), '',s)
print(s)
```

gives this:

```
'https://google.com'
```

Comment: You can find here a list of the characters  the regex operator tild **~** works on [~ operator](https://catonmat.net/my-favorite-regex)