# Removing xml unicode characters from strings

Tags: python, unicode

I'm struggling to remove xml unicode characters from strings.  Adapting [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36598450/1156245) for Python 3 fails:

```
s = 'foo&#x421;&#x44A;&#x431;bar'
s.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
# b'foo&#x421;&#x44A;&#x431;bar'
```

I've also tried [unescaping with xml.sax.saxutils](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml) but with no luck:

```
unescape(s).encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
# b'foo&#x421;&#x44A;bar'
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to competely remove them, or just translate them correctly?  `print(html.unescape(s))` gives `fooСъбbar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might harness [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) for this task

```
import html
s = 'foo&#x421;&#x44A;&#x431;bar'
s2 = html.unescape(s).encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
print(s2)
```

output:

```
b'foobar'
```

Comment: What if the XML escape represents an ASCII character?.  It will be replaced, not removed.